# div floats out in enternet explorer 11

Tags: html, css

This is a jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MF4KN/

This is on Chrome
[image]

This is on IE
[image]

please see how the div is out the box in IE,

**I am using IE11**

The wrong div has this ID `manual_add`

This is the css

```
#map_manual_address_container {
    width:700px;
    height:410px;
}


#map_canvas { width: 400px; height: 400px; 
              float:left;
}


#mamual_address {
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    height:410px;
}
#mamual_address textarea {
    height:400px;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<fieldset>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
                <div id="map_manual_address_container">
                    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                    <div id="mamual_address">
                        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Try containing the floats on ```#map_manual_address_container``` with ```overflow: hidden;```

Comment: @Dominik no please , that is exactly what I dont want. I want the IE version to be exactly like the chrome version but in your solution, the chrome version would be like the IE version

Comment: Ehm I am not sure what you mean. Containing the float means it will _NOT_ have the addresses container float outside of its wrapper... Also I added my code to your fiddle and it does look the same as what it did before in Chrome... I was just not able to test in IE11

Comment: @Dominik so please give me your new jfiddle and I will test it on my IE11.

Comment: OK I just tested it in IE11 and the float is not your problem but the fieldset that's got ```width: 80%;``` on it. You'll have to change the way to display that popup to give it dynamic width or change the width of the fieldset with JS as soon as you hit the view with the map.

Comment: @Dominik so why it is working well on chrome and firefox , but not on IE please, if the code was wrong, would it work on chrome in the first place?

Comment: Mate I would fix the overlaying issue first and then go into the "Why is code differently interpreted on different browsers"-rant ;) That your wrapper width doesn't change even though your inner div does seems off to me in this case.

Comment: Chrome and other browsers are not obeying the width setting because the content is too wide. IE is faithfully obeying your width declaration. Not sure which is the "correct" behavior, but if you don't want IE to obey that rule, just remove it!

Comment: @ralph.m sorry but remove what please? :)

Comment: @Dominik so you are suggesting to change the width everytime I go that view and then reduce it when I go to another div? right?

Comment: Well either that or you center your div differently so I can handle ```width: auto;```

Comment: Note that even in Chrome the position of your wrapper is off as it's not in the middle anymore... When you fix that you'll fix your other problem as well.

Comment: I meant remove this: `#msform fieldset {width: 80%;}`

Comment: @ralph.m could you help by a jfiddle please?

Comment: @Dominik please could you help me with the correction with a jfiddble please? apprecite that really.

Comment: guys, I have to go to sleep because i need to go to work after 2.5 hour :) I will catch you tomorrow, really appreciate your time. good night